# Lining up DNA base pairs in an array

Tags: python, arrays

Trying to import a series of base pairs into an array.

I want it in the form `['AA','AT','AG','AC'...]`

Here's my code:

```
paths = [str(x[4:7]) for x in mm_start]

paths
['A A', 'A T', 'A G', 'A C', 'T A', 'T T', 'T G', 'T C', 'G A', 'G T', 'G G', 'G C', 'C A', 'C T', 'C G', 'C C']
```

I get spaces in between the letters!
This strip command isn't helping either.

```
paths = str(paths).replace(" ","")

paths
"['AA','AT','AG','AC','TA','TT','TG','TC','GA','GT','GG','GC','CA','CT','CG','CC']"
```

Now I get a (") at the beginning and end of this array.

Any ideas very welcome!

The text file has the base pairs laid out

```
1 2 3 4 A A
1 2 3 1 A T
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the list into a string. You really want to say

```
paths = [pair.replace(" ", "") for pair in paths]
```

That iterates over each pair in your list of strings and removes spaces rather than converting the entire list to a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
paths = str(paths).replace(" ","")
```

Well of course it doesn't work, because you converted the *list* to a string (and you didn't convert it back). What you need to do is apply the `replace` to each element of the list, not to the string expression of the list.

```
paths = [str(x[4:7]).replace(" ","") for x in mm_start]
```

(that's only one way of many).